# For-loop only running 1 time - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I want to loop an array but unfortunately my for-loop only executes 1 time.

This is my code:

```
var cmpz_disabled_dates=$.parseJSON(disabled_dates);
var date = new Date();
console.log(cmpz_disabled_dates);
for (i = 0; i < cmpz_disabled_dates.length; i++) {
    var type = cmpz_disabled_dates[i]["type"];
        if(type === "ebdida_day")   {
            var disabled_day = Number(cmpz_disabled_dates[i]["disabled"]) + 1;
            if(disabled_day == 8)   {
                disabled_day = 0;
            }
            var day = date.getDay();
            console.log(i,date,day,disabled_day);
            return [(disabled_day != day)];
    }
}
```

OUTPUT of console.log(cmpz_disabled_dates);

```
0: {type: "ebdida_day", disabled: "7", repeat: "off", calendar: "start_end"}
1: {type: "ebdida_date_range", disabled: Array(2), repeat: "on", calendar: "start_end"}
2: {type: "ebdida_date", disabled: "2020-04-10", repeat: "off", calendar: "start_end"}
3: {type: "ebdida_date", disabled: "2020-04-13", repeat: "off", calendar: "start_end"}
4: {type: "ebdida_date_range", disabled: Array(2), repeat: "off", calendar: "start_end"}
5: {type: "ebdida_date", disabled: "2020-05-01", repeat: "off", calendar: "start_end"}
6: {type: "ebdida_date", disabled: "2020-05-21", repeat: "off", calendar: "start_end"}
7: {type: "ebdida_date", disabled: "2020-06-01", repeat: "off", calendar: "start_end"}
8: {type: "ebdida_date_range", disabled: Array(2), repeat: "off", calendar: "start_end"}
9: {type: "ebdida_date_range", disabled: Array(2), repeat: "off", calendar: "start_end"}
10: {type: "ebdida_date_range", disabled: Array(2), repeat: "off", calendar: "start_end"}
11: {type: "ebdida_date_range", disabled: Array(2), repeat: "off", calendar: "start_end"}
12: {type: "ebdida_date_range", disabled: Array(2), repeat: "off", calendar: "start_end"}
13: {type: "ebdida_day", disabled: "3", repeat: "off", calendar: "start_end"}
14: {type: "ebdida_day", disabled: "6", repeat: "off", calendar: "start_end"}
length: 15
```

OUTPUT of console.log(i,date,day,disabled_day);

```
0 Wed Sep 23 2020 08:48:48 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit) 3 0
```

--> so it is only outputting element 0, the elements 13 and 14 (which are also from type "ebdida_day") are not outputted

I think, the for-loop is overwriting something but I cannot find the bug. Thanks!

Comment: A return inside a loop breaks that loop on the first iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove return statement in your for loop

Comment: OK I get it. 
I needed the return but now I managed to only break the loop when it get "false". Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have a `return` which breaks the iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Set return statement outside the for loop block, otherwise the iteration stops

```js
var cmpz_disabled_dates=$.parseJSON(disabled_dates);
var date = new Date();
console.log(cmpz_disabled_dates);
for (i = 0; i < cmpz_disabled_dates.length; i++) {
    var type = cmpz_disabled_dates[i]["type"];
        if(type === "ebdida_day")   {
            var disabled_day = Number(cmpz_disabled_dates[i]["disabled"]) + 1;
            if(disabled_day == 8)   {
                disabled_day = 0;
            }
            var day = date.getDay();
            console.log(i,date,day,disabled_day);        
    }
    return [(disabled_day != day)];
}
```